# Ansible debg module colorful output resembling tput echo

Tags: ansible

My shell script echoes status in colorful texts. I used register variable to store the output. Used debug module to output it. But instead of colorful texts all it does is append like :

> "stdout_lines": [    "\u001b[31mRed text \u001b[47mand white
>   background\u001b(B\u001b[0m" ]

I actually want it to be Red text and white background

My sample playbook looks like this:

- name: output shell scripts with color

  shell: `'echo "$(tput setaf 1)Red text $(tput setab 7)and white background$(tput sgr 0)"'`

  register: `echo_output`

  - debug: `var=echo_output`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got the output:
shell: 'echo "$(tput setaf 1)Red text $(tput setab 7)and white background$(tput sgr 0)" > /dev/tty'